# C# Unable to multiply two figures together

Tags: c#

Im trying to multiply a variable by another variable, who's value is stored in another class.
In context, I'm trying to multiply an employees hours for the month by the hourly rate the employee gets paid by.

C# Employee class

Im getting the error in the method "payHourly"

```
    class HourlyEmployee : Employee
{
    private HourlyRate m_hourlyRate;   //The amount an employee is to be paid per hour


    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p_employeeID"></param>
    /// <param name="p_employeeName"></param>
    /// <param name="p_employeeAge"></param>
    /// <param name="aRate"></param>
    public HourlyEmployee(int p_employeeID, string p_employeeName, int p_employeeAge, HourlyRate aRate)
    {
        m_employeeID = p_employeeID;
        m_employeeName = p_employeeName;
        m_employeeAge = p_employeeAge;

        m_hourlyRate.setEmployee(this);
    }

    public void payHourly(int hoursWorked)
    {
        int wage;
        wage = hoursWorked * m_hourlyRate;

    }
}
```

HourlyRate Class

```
    class HourlyRate
{
    private decimal m_hourlyRate;
    private HourlyEmployee m_employee;

    public HourlyRate(decimal p_hourlyRate)
    {
        m_hourlyRate = p_hourlyRate;
    }

    public void setEmployee(HourlyEmployee aEmployee)
    {
        m_employee = aEmployee;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: What's the error, and on what line?

Comment: you can not multiply an int with a "HourlyRate" class/struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wage = hoursWorked * m_hourlyRate;` ??

m_hourlyRate is object instance !

you need to use :

```
wage = hoursWorked * m_hourlyRate.m_hourlyRate;
```

Using Object Name same as an attribute inside the object is confusing. `Change private HourlyRate m_hourlyRate` to something else.

**Edited :**

Also , change : 
`private decimal m_hourlyRate;`
to 
`public decimal m_hourlyRate { set; get; }` in order to access it.

**OR**

```
  class HourlyRate
{
    private decimal m_hourlyRate;
    private HourlyEmployee m_employee;

    public HourlyRate(decimal p_hourlyRate)
    {
        m_hourlyRate = p_hourlyRate;
    }

    public void setEmployee(HourlyEmployee aEmployee)
    {
        m_employee = aEmployee;
    }

   public decimal GetHourlyRate()
   {
      return m_hourlyRate;
   }
}
```

then use :

```
wage = hoursWorked * m_hourlyRate.GetHourlyRate();
```

Comment: That's fixed the first error but now i can't access it due to it's protection level..
It's a private attribute, should I make it protected?

Comment: Edited , using getter.

Comment: the getter didn't work but thankyou for fixing the first error

Comment: @KyleHodgetts you changed private to public ?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot multiply m_hourlyRate with an integer
you've to use this
wage = m_horulyRate.m_hourlyRate * hoursWorked;

Comment: I just noticed that, i've changed wage to decimal :)